# Is there any reason for using if(1 || !Foo())?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, syntax, logical-operators

I read some legacy code:

```
if ( 1 || !Foo() )
```

Is there any seen reason why not to write:

```
if ( !Foo() )
```

Comment: '1 || something()'  will always yield true. So the two statements are not equivalent, but as to why this is done, pass.

Comment: `if (1 || !foo())` <==> `if (1)`.

Comment: Why not just to remove the conditional? You say that `1 || foo()` == `foo()`. This means that the code behind them is useless. You may remove it altogether with the conditions.

Comment: Most probably this was done temporarily to force the conditional to true (maybe a bug, workaround or refactoring) and not put back. Use the annotate/blame feature of your source control to find the version where this changed -- you might get a useful comment or bug database entry to help work out why it was changed

Comment: Maybe Foo() is implemented as `return rand() % 2;`

Comment: `1 && !Foo()` is equal to `!Foo()`

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The two are **not** the same. The first will never evaluate `Foo()` because the `1` short-circuits the `||`.

Why it's done - probably someone wanted to force entry in the `then` branch for debugging purposes and left it there. It could also be that this was written before source control, so they didn't want the code to be lost, rather just bypassed *for now*.

Comment: Sounds like something that what inserted during development/debugging, and left there either because someone forgot to remove it, or by fear of breaking something.

Comment: In any case this is a better solution than commenting out because the compiler keeps checking the inactive code. I do this all the time for debugging reasons.

Comment: only really really experienced developer know this. +1

Answer (score 44):

`if (1 || !Foo() )` will be always satisfied. `!Foo()` will not even be reached because of [short-circuits evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

This happens when you want to make sure that the code below the `if` will be executed, but you don't want to remove the *real* condition in it, probably for debug purposes.

Additional information that might help you:

- `if(a && b)` - if `a` is `false`, `b` won't be checked.
- `if(a && b)` - if `a` is `true`, `b` will be checked, because if it's `false`, the expression will be `false`.
- `if(a || b)` - if `a` is `true`, `b` won't be checked, because this is `true` anyway.
- `if(a || b)` - if `a` is `false`, `b` will be checked, because if `b` is `true` then it'll be `true`.

---

It's highly recommended to have a macro for this purpose, say `DEBUG_ON 1`, that will make it easier to understand what the programmer means, and not to have *magic numbers* in the code (Thanks @grigeshchauhan).

Comment: So `if(1 || !Foo() ) {code}` == `if(1){code}` == `{code}` while `if (!Foo())` can be either `{code}` or just `;` depends on value returned by `Foo()`. :)

Comment: I extend you last expressions.. EDIT: for debugging purpose either use a macro `DEGUG_ON = 1` or comment it. `if (DEGUG_ON || !Foo()) ` (in fact I will comment code). ;)

Comment: *"It's highly recommended to have a macro for this purpose, say DEBUG_ON 1"*... yes except code readability is your last concern when you're trying to find that damn bug :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad Indeed. But this bug check could turn into a bug itself.. Or mae a confusion, like it made to OP :D

Answer (score 11):

```
1 || condition
```

is always true, regardless whether the `condition` is true or not. In this case, the `condition` is never even being evaluated. The following code:

```
int c = 5;
if (1 || c++){}
printf("%d", c);
```

outputs `5` since `c` is never incremented, however if you changed `1` to `0`, the `c++` would be actually called, making the output `6`.

---

A usual practical usage of this is in the situation when you want to test some piece of code that is being invoked when the condition that evaluates to true only seldom is met:

```
if (1 || condition ) {
    // code I want to test
}
```

This way `condition` will never be evaluated and therefore `// code I want to test` always invoked. However it is definitely not the same as:

```
if (condition) { ...
```

which is a statement where `condition` will actually be evaluated (and in your case `Foo` will be called)

Comment: *`you don't want to wait till that condition will evaluate to true`* yes basically  short-circuits is a technique to save executions!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I was not referring to performance, neither time of execution. I was referring to specific criteria being met.

Comment: ouch that's a strange language feature. I was believing that conding was always evaluated if it had side effects (so basically I was believeing that non-const methods and static functions was evaluated, but I tried in a simple "hello world" and was never able to get condition evaluated in the first case O_O

Answer (score 10):

The question was answered properly - the difference is the right side of the or operation is short-circuited, suggesting this is debug code to force entry into the if block.

But in the interest of best practices, at least my rough stab at a best practice, I'd suggest alternatives, in order of increasing preference (best is last):

note:  noticed after I coded examples this was a C++ question, examples are C#.  Hopefully you can translate.  If anyone needs me to, just post a comment.

In-line comment:

```
if (1 /*condition*/) //temporary debug
```

Out-of-line comment:

```
//if(condition)
if(true) //temporary debug
```

Name-Indicative Function

```
//in some general-use container
bool ForceConditionForDebug(bool forcedResult, string IgnoredResult)
{
      #if DEBUG
          Debug.WriteLine(
              string.Format(
                  "Conditional {0} forced to {1} for debug purposes",
                  IgnoredResult,
                  forcedResult));
          return forcedResult;
      #else
          #if ALLOW_DEBUG_CODE_IN_RELEASE
              return forcedResult;
          #else
              throw new ApplicationException("Debug code detected in release mode");
          #endif
      #endif
}

//Where used
if(ForceConditionForDebug(true, "condition"))...

//Our case
if(ForceConditionForDebug(true, "!Foo()"))...
```

And if you wanted a really robust solution, you could add a repository rule to source control to reject any checked in code that called ForceConditionForDebug.  This code should never have been written that way because it obviously doesn't communicate intent.  It never should have been checked in (or have been allowed to be checked in) (source control?  peer review?)  And it should definitely never be allowed to execute in production in its current form.