# Is order of evaluation gauranteed with short circuit evaluation?

Tags: c, arrays, lazy-evaluation

Is the left part of the `&&` always evaluated before the right part?

I want to know because I'm wondering if I can change

```
if(i > 0)
    if(someFunc(arr[i-1], arr[i]))
        //do work
```

to

`if(i > 0 && someFunc(arr[i-1], arr[i]))`

or would this cause undefined behaviour if the right side gets evaluated first and `arr[0-1]`is referenced?

Comment: yes, guaranteed by C.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because of [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior of logical `&&` operator, in case of `&&` second expression evaluates only  when first is true. Read following:

> #### 6.5.13 Logical AND operator
>
> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees `left-to-right` evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand
>   compares equal to 0, the second operand is **not** evaluated.

<sup>From [Is short-circuiting boolean operators mandated in C/C++? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)</sup>

So  if `i > 0` is false (for example if `i = 0`) then result of `i > 0` expression will be false, and then second operand  `someFunc(arr[i-1], arr[i]` will not be called (evaluated).

Accordingly,  `if(i > 0 && someFunc(arr[i-1], arr[i]))` is safe to code, but be-careful `i - 1` shouldn't be > max index value of `arr[]`. Really I will prefer this form of if compare to nested if blocks (flat is better then nested).

From @[Maroun Maroun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173540)'s answer ["Is there any reason for asking `if(1 || Foo())`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292371/1673391) Additional information that might help you:

> - `if(a && b)` - if `a` is `false`, `b` won't be checked.
> - `if(a && b)` - if `a` is `true`, `b` will be checked, because if it's `false`, the expression will be `false`.
> - `if(a || b)` - if `a` is `true`, `b` won't be checked, because this is `true` anyway.
> - `if(a || b)` - if `a` is `false`, `b` will be checked, because if `b` is `true` then it'll be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Order of evaluation for the operators `&&`, `||`, `,` and `? :`(ternary operator) are guaranteed from left to right. A [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) occurs between the left and right sub-expression of these operands.  All the side effects of the left sub-expression of these operators (`&&`, `||` and `,`) are completed before any access to its right sub-expression.

> would this cause undefined behavior if the right side gets evaluated first and `arr[0-1]` is referenced?

Yes. If that were the case, it would cause undefined behavior. (But it doesn't happen that way, so there won't be any undefined behavior.)